# Excel creating a new list from an existing list of names

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a spreadsheet which requires me to take an existing list of names, id's and emails, and then create other lists from this which include multiple instances of each of these categories.

For example, if I have a column of names: John, Ben, James and I want to create a new column where each name repeats 3 times: John, John, John, Ben, Ben, Ben, James, James, James.

Is there a quicker way to do this rather than copying and pasting each name?

At the moment I am simply doing this manually and it is taking a really long time.